# C# selenium chromedriver proxy auth

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

im writing a automation tool in visual studio with c#.

im using selenium with chromedriver. i need proxy user pass auth for my session. But i try so many times and so many sources but didnt work.

How to basicly user pass ip port proxy for my chromedriver session. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you share code for how you start your webdriver and set your browser capabilities. I think that is where we need to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.

#### Configuring a proxy using `ChromeOptions` and `org.openqa.selenium.Proxy`

If you want the solution to be easily portable to run on other systems, you can try configuring a proxy using `ChromeOptions` and `org.openqa.selenium.Proxy`. There will be some additional methods in here to configure your proxy, but we need to know what type of proxy and type of authentication is supported.

```
// Add the WebDriver proxy capability.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myhttpproxy:3337");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

// Add a ChromeDriver-specific capability.
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

#### Create a new chrome profile with proxy configuration

Alternatively, you could create a profile for chrome with the proxy configured and tell chrome driver to work with that. This would be difficult, if not impossible, to port to other systems without manual setup, unless you containerized it, but that's out of scope here.

As of chrome 71, head to chrome settings at `chrome://settings/` and choose Manage other people. Create a new person to represent your proxy profile. Configure the proxy using the browser the way you normally would for manually connecting.

Locate the path to your profile, something like: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1` if you're on windows. You can easily find by navigating to `chrome://version/` and looking for `Profile Path`

Utilize `ChromeOptions` to pass the option for setting the user data directory for chrome on startup

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

Some snippets pulled from documentation for [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

Comment: hi brian. thanks for your help.

but i tryed this code, proxy login pass popup.. how to user:pass proxy login?

Comment: You need to provide more information: "There will be some additional methods in here to configure your proxy, but we need to know what type of proxy and type of authentication is supported."

Comment: Anybody figure out a solution to handle the proxy authentication?

Comment: he is talking about http proxy authentication